# How to run Django project in background

Tags: python, django, server

Recent I am running Django project on terminal using this command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

But Server is stopped by closing terminal, So I need to run server in background.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using this command for production ?

Comment: Minimize terminal?

Comment: When developing, why don't you want the terminal? It's content is useful for debugging. In production, you ought not to be using the development server.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `nohup`, an output of the command will not be set what will not be created in the command (where or was executed)

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

If you are using some automation software, in order not to crash the deployment, add an '&' at the end of the command, like this

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nohup` command, so your command runs without the terminal and all the outputs from the program will go to the file `nohup.out` (in the same directory you ran the command).

Use like so:

```sh
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Comment: thank you. I have to install any package for nohup in terminal?

Comment: It is likely preinstalled, flag as an answer if it did work out for you! :)

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 &
```

"&" puts the executed command in background and sets init as it's parent process when you close the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can use [screen](https://www.shellhacks.com/linux-screen-command-run-in-background/) to run a program in background.

This should [answer your question](https://superuser.com/questions/632205/continue-ssh-background-task-jobs-when-closing-ssh)