# prevent closing of python app using windows CMD X button (by mistake)

Tags: python, django, windows

I have a running Django app (localy)
in "start.bat" file.

```
CALL venv\Scripts\activate.bat
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --insecure --noreload
```

Someone on the PC sometimes close the window [image]
How can I prevent this?
like: warning popup with prompet / hide X button / run in different app than CMD ?

I did run it on TK gui but it was messing with my process manager inside the Django.

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71853068

Comment: Running django runserver in background

Comment: Or run django in docker/nignx but it is slightly more complex

Comment: I am on Windows

Comment: Maybe there is another Terminal replacing the CMD ? that can run python.

Comment: Did you try what I posted at the first comment?

Comment: I run on windows ... nohup for linux. anyway I just used a terminal that prevent closing without a pop up. looking fotlr cmd alternative on Google.